# Java web start security issue

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm having a strange problem. I have a Java application which I want to run using Java web start. This Java application is signed by a trusted authority (digicert) certificate. When I deploy my application to my local glass fish 4.1 server and run the Java I get the dialogue "do you want to trust ....). So far so good. When I deploy the exact same app to a glass fish server hosted on a remote machine (Amazon instance) and attempt to run the Java web start app, I get. "This application is blocked" message, as if the Java app is not signed. What is the cause of this behavior? My remote server uses ssl connections, but even when I specify http in the jnlp I get the same problem (my server listens to both http and https). This has been driving me crazy for three days now. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are other hoops to jump through.  You need a permissions applet 
tag, and the main jar has to have a matching permissions line, and
a codebase line compatible with the site being loaded from.
All the jars have to be listed in the jnlp.

Comment: I have done these things. As I said,everything works fine on my local server. I get the problem when I upload my web app to the remote server.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with amazon hosting.

Comment: compare it with a deployment to a local VM having a distinct IP from your local machine, to ensure that similar trust rules are being applied.  Use the browser tools to ensure that everything is being downloaded.  Is codebase set to a value that causes the remote download of the jars to fail?